# How to apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'ISession'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, type-conversion, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

I'm struggling with that problem : I'm trying to retrieve my user from his session by using :

```
var user = HttpContext.Session.Get("User");
```

But at the same time, I'm trying to convert it as a BusinessCustomer object :

```
var user = Convert.ToHttpContext.Session.GetString("User") as BusinessCustomer;
```

As there is no link of inheritance the problem occurs and I don't know how to fix it

I'm thinking of serialize the user and then create an object of BusinessCustomer and fill it with the parameters but I don't know if their are others ways.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> First you create this class

```
public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetObject(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public static T GetObject<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
    }
}
```

> Then for set value on it

```
   var user = new User();
   HttpContext.Session.SetObject("User", user);
```

> finaly get your value

```
var sessionUser = HttpContext.Session.GetObject<User>("User");
```